# Any refactoring suggestion

Tags: java, selenium

I have a long switch statement code(around 8 cases) that decide what search by to use to find an element in the browser.
Any suggestion how to refactor this code?

WebElement CurrentObject = null;
switch (SearchBy) {
        case "className":
            try {
                CurrentObject = new WebDriverWait(driver, ConstantValues.LONGWAIT)
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className(SearchPar)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Element not found: " + e);
            }
            break;

```
    case "cssSelector":
        try {
            CurrentObject = new WebDriverWait(driver, ConstantValues.LONGWAIT)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(SearchPar)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Element not found: " + e);
        }
        break;

    case "id":
        try {
            CurrentObject = new WebDriverWait(driver, ConstantValues.LONGWAIT)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(SearchPar)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Element not found: " + e);
        }
        break;

    case "linkText":
        try {
            CurrentObject = new WebDriverWait(driver, ConstantValues.LONGWAIT)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText(SearchPar)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Element not found: " + e);
        }
        break;

    case "name":
        try {
            CurrentObject = new WebDriverWait(driver, ConstantValues.LONGWAIT)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name(SearchPar)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Element not found: " + e);
        }
        break;
   default:
        System.out.println(">>> SEARCH BY KEYWORD IS NOT VALID! <<<");
    }
```

Comment: Refactoring questions could be more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Hint: look at duplicated code and try to move it out of the switch statement.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt this code is working find I just need suggestion to make it better. I'm already working your idea on removing duplicate codes and make a function then call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend not to write your code in this way, create a framework instead.

Create a SeleniumUtility class (or any name you want) and write methods like this:
Example (You may remove WebDriver driver)

```
/**
 * Method returns WebElement by Xpath.
 * 
 * @param String xpathExpression
 * @param WebDriver driver
 * @return WebElement
 */
public WebElement getElementByXpath(String xpathExpression, WebDriver driver){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression));
}

/**
 * Method returns WebElement by ID.
 * 
 * @param String id
 * @param WebDriver driver
 * @return WebElement
 */
public WebElement getElementByID(String id, WebDriver driver){
    return driver.findElement(By.id(id));
}
```

Or something like this:

```
/**
 * Method returns By.
 * 
 * @param String identifier Example: xpath,id,name etc
 * @param String expression Example: //*[@class='text']
 * @return By
 */
public By getBy(String identifier, String expression){
    switch (identifier.toLowerCase()) {
    case "xpath":
        return By.xpath(expression);
    case "id":
        return By.id(expression);
    case "name":
        return By.name(expression);
    case "classname":
        return By.className(expression);
    case "cssselector":
        return By.cssSelector(expression);
    case "linktext":
        return By.linkText(expression);
    case "partiallinktext":
        return By.partialLinkText(expression);
    case "tagname":
        return By.tagName(expression);
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid identifier passed: " + identifier);
    }
}
```

Write Explicit wait and fluent waits in a different class and use it again and again.

Now your entire code would be something like this:

```
        try {
            CurrentObject = waitTillElementLocated(getBy("cssselector","SearchPar"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Element not found: " + e);
        }
```

OR

```
        try {
            CurrentObject = waitTillElementLocated(getBy("id","SearchPar"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Element not found: " + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Switch-case` is an anti-pattern in many programming language. To avoid them, you can use some technique like `Replace conditional with polymorphism` in Java. I suggest use them with `Reflection`.It is a feature of Java.

Answer (score 0):

If searchBy always matches a method name, then I think reflection could be the solution.

```
Method searchMethod = By.class.getMethod(searchBy, returnClass.class);
CurrentObject = new WebDriverWait(driver, ConstantValues.LONGWAIT).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(searchMethod.invoke(null,searchPar);
```

You would have to catch a few possible Exceptions.